# how to add filter to nattable in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: nattable

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, 
            new ComboBoxCellEditor(Arrays.asList("200536", "200538")), 
            DisplayMode.NORMAL, 
            FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + 2);
    //
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, 
            new ComboBoxCellEditor(Arrays.asList("07")), 
            DisplayMode.NORMAL, 
            FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + 3);
    final Style rowStyle = new Style();
    rowStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper
            .getColor(197, 212, 231));
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, rowStyle, 
            DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);
```

i tried to add filters in nattable but the ComboBox didn't appear yet ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a layer composition that contains a filter row. Have a look at our examples application to see how this is done in various scenarios.

Comment: thank you for your answer, where i can find the examples ?